# Xml Holder how to find a value based on a condition - Groovy

Tags: soapui

How do I use XML holder in groovy in order to find the Amount that belongs to all instances of Test1 in the xml below?

```
<BigTest>
  <TestHeader>
    <Name>Test</Name>
    <Amount>5.00</Amount>
  </TestHeader>
  <TestHeader>
    <Name>Test</Name>
    <Amount>10.00</Amount>
  </TestHeader>
  <TestHeader>
    <Name>Test1</Name>
    <Amount>35.00</Amount>
  </TestHeader>
  <TestHeader>
    <Name>Test1</Name>
    <Amount>25.00</Amount>
  </TestHeader>
  <TestHeader>
    <Name>Test2</Name>
    <Amount>5.00</Amount>
  </TestHeader>
</BigTest>
```

At the moment I am getting a `[]` response when I try the following:

```
log.info holder.getDomNodes("//*:TestHeader/*:Amount[Name = 'Test1']/text()").nodeValue
```

Comment: Coudl you please see the answer mentioned below. It worked for me

Answer (score 1):

```
def groovyUtils=new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)

def holder=groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("StepName#Response")

def a = holder.getNodeValues("//*:BigTest//*:TestHeader[Name='Test1']//*:Amount")

 for(def var in a)
 {
    log.info var
 }
```

Just need to replace 'StepName' with your request step.

```
holder.getNodeValues("//*:BigTest//*:TestHeader[Name='Test1']//*:Amount")
```

will do it for you

[image]